# Flash to Javascript RIA conversion

Tags: javascript, user-interface, ria

A few years back I made my own version of this RIA using Flash/Actionscript:

http://www.asfusion.com/apps/homelocator/

I am wondering if this type of RIA is possible using Javascript/HTML/CSS ?

I have searched for a few hours and not really found anything similar.

Does anyone know of a similar RIA created with Javascript/HTML/CSS ?

Answer (score 1):

The application under link generates error now.

But from what I see it's possible to reimplement it with JS/HTML5 and the bunch of JS based frameworks like Angular or React.

If you could describe what are the custom features, then I'm able to create more detailed recommendations.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be possible on html5 canvas.

Comment: Do you have any specific examples of html5 canvas RIAs that are similar to  -  http://www.asfusion.com/apps/homelocator/

Comment: After looking at the link i see most of that can be achieved through jQuery UI itself.